# AS3 and sortOn method

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

This code :

```
var a:Array = [
                {max:10},
                {max:2},
                {max:6},
            ];

a.sortOn(["max"]);


for(var s:String in a)
{
    trace("max-> " + a[s]["max"]);
}
```

returns me :

```
10 
2 
6
```

and not

```
2
6
10
```

Why please ?

Comment: ok I forgot to use Array.NUMERIC

Answer (score 1):

Try `a.sortOn("max", Array.NUMERIC);`. There are some examples on the documentation, this is where i got the example from.

Answer (score 0):

It automatically sorts everything as a String, unless you tell it otherwise.